# Why does changing this layout_weight value not affect my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

What is difference between these two cases:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
```

I can't see any difference in my UI. So what is difference between the above two examples?

Comment: You can use `layout_weight` > 1 if `weightSum ` property is used. Read android documentation for more.

Comment: Actually, you can use `layout_weight` > 1 with or without specifying a `weightSum`.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a difference if the container `LinearLayout` had a weightSum set. From the documentation for [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum):

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

You are using the first case currently (I suspect), so the weightSum is calculated as 1 in your first example, and 3 in the second, so in both instances the weighted View takes up all the width not used by other (non-weighted) Views.

If you manually set the weightSum to 4 in both examples, you should see the View in the first example taking up 1/4 of the width not used by other (non-weighted) Views, and the View in the second example taking up 3/4 of the width not used by other (non-weighted) Views.